# inno setup installing sql server 2005 and after updating database

Tags: sql-server-2005, inno-setup

I want to use silent install of sql server 2005 express and after I want to update database. I used inno setup script wizard and I selected SQLEXPR.exe as installing application and the sql file which I want to update database after installing the sql server 2005 express."emin.sql" is a file that I want to update database after installing sql server.

Here is my code which is generated by wizard;

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "SQLEXPR.EXE"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{B6B8AFF5-6C3D-4673-8179-EE9C5C0A5072}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\SQL Server 2005 Express\SQLEXPR.EXE"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\emin.sql"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Why do you deploy 10 years old DBMS ? Have you tried to run `sqlexpr.exe /?` from command prompt to inspect the command line parameters of the SQL Server installer (you should do more than just running it silently) ? You should also check whether the server is already installed. Finally, if you install the server, you must create a database first (since you've said that you want to *update database*).

Comment: I will use sql server 2008.  I am  only using trial and error method for creating setup file. I need to setup file that controls if the sql server exist or not and after it will install it or not.